# html5 crashes while uploading large images

Tags: html, filereader

Here the problem in below code is that when i want to show thumbnails for 40 large images . the firefox in windows is crashing as the cpu usage increases while loading one image after other.i know its because loading the image of full size (around 9000 Kb).is there any way just to show thumbnail rather than loading full size in html5...

dropbox.addEventListener("drop", dropUpload, false);

function dropUpload(event) 
{

noop(event);
var dropMethod = event.dataTransfer;

```
var classicMethod = event.target;

var filesDone =0;

var dropedFiles = (dropMethod == undefined) ? classicMethod.files: dropMethod.files;
function next() {
    if (filesDone < dropedFiles.length) {
        addFileThumbnails(dropedFiles[filesDone++], next);
    }
}
// do the first one
next();
```

}

function addFileThumbnails(file,doneCallback) {

```
var li = document.createElement("li"),
div = document.createElement("div"),
img,
progressBarContainer = document.createElement("div"),
progressBar = document.createElement("div"),
tBody;
li.appendChild(div);

progressBarContainer.className = "progress-bar-container";
progressBar.className = "progress-bar";
progressBar.setAttribute("id", "proBar_" + (indexN++));
progressBarContainer.appendChild(progressBar);
li.appendChild(progressBarContainer);
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onerror = function(event) {
    alert("couldn't read file "
            + event.target.error.code);
};
// Present file info and append it to the list of files

if (reader !== "undefined" && (/image/i).test(file.type)) {
    img = document.createElement("img");
    img.setAttribute("class", "thumb");
    img.setAttribute("id", "img_" + (indexN++));
    reader.onload = (function (img) {
        return function (evt) {
            img.src = evt.target.result;
            doneCallback();
    };

    }(img));
    var ret = reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    img.onload= function(){
      ctx.drawImage(img,100,100)
    }
}

reader.addEventListener("progress", function (evt) {
    if (evt.lengthComputable) {
        progressBar.style.width= (evt.loaded / evt.total) * 100 + "%";
    }

}, false);

// File uploaded
reader.addEventListener("load", function () {
    progressBarContainer.className += " uploaded";
    progressBar.innerHTML = "";
}, false);

fileInfo = "Name:" + file.name + "</br>";
fileInfo += "Size:" + parseInt(file.size / 1024, 10) + " kb</br>";
fileInfo += "Type:" + file.type;
div.setAttribute("id", "desc_" + img.id.substring(4));
div.innerHTML = fileInfo;


tBody = getTableBodyLayout(img,li);
document.getElementById("images_table").appendChild(tBody);
moveScrollbar();
```

}